# The difference of two fair dice rolls

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, dice

If you roll a dice twice, and subtract $ Result_1 $ from $ Result_2 $, in what interval with 97% probability will lie number of all zeros, if we will do this experiment 1200 times.

I assume, I should use Chebyshev's inequality. 
For one experiment, the chance of getting zero is $ 6/36 $.

How should I apply Chebyshev's inequality in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The number $X$ of zeros is a binomial random variable with $n=1200$ and $p=1/6$. It has mean $\mu=np=200$ and variance $\sigma^2=np(1-p)=500/3$ and so standard deviation $\sigma=\sqrt{500/3}\approx 12.91$. Approximate $X$ with a normal random variable, which is OK by the central limit theorem, to get
$$.97\approx \Pr\left(-2.17\leq {X-\mu\over \sigma}\leq 2.17\right)\approx P(172\leq X\leq 228),$$
so the required interval is $[172,228]$.

By the way, the actual probability $P(172\leq X\leq 228)$ is closer to $.9728$.